# Why is the image of a faithful representation of a Lie group a Lie subgroup?

Tags: differential-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $\varphi:G\to\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ be a faithful Lie group representation, i.e. an injective Lie group homomorphism. Then is $\varphi(G)$ a Lie subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$? Somehow I think this shouldn't be to difficult to see, but I don't quite get it. I know that $\varphi(G)$ is an immersed submanifold because $\varphi$ is injective and of constant rank, but how to show that the multiplication $m:\varphi(G)\times\varphi(G)\to\varphi(G)$ is smooth?

Comment: Show that matrix multiplication is smooth.

Comment: @Chickenmancer Yes but why is it smooth when corestircted to $\varphi(G)$?

Comment: Although $\varphi$ is an immersion, it need not be an embedding.

Comment: While not necessarily an embedding, $\varphi$ is a *weak* embedding (as is the inclusion of any Lie subgroup). This allows multiplication to be smoothly restricted to its image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are perhaps confused about the definitions, specifically the definition of *Lie subgroup* (which you have not specified in your question; I will do so below following the most common convention).

An *immersion* is a $C^\infty$ map $\phi:N \to M$ between manifolds such that the differential $d \phi_n$ is injective at each $n \in N$. A *submanifold* of a manifold $M$ is a pair $(N,\phi)$ consisting of a manifold $N$ and a one-to-one immersion $\phi:N \to M$. If $G$ is a Lie group, a *Lie subgroup* of $G$ is a pair consisting of a Lie group $H$ and a group homomorphism $\phi: H \to G$ such that the pair $(H,\phi)$ is a submanifold of the manifold $G$.

With these definitions it is clear that checking that a faithful representation $\phi:G \to \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{R})$ is a Lie subgroup amounts to checking that it is an immersion (which it is, as you have written above---though I would rather see it by observing that it suffices to prove that it is an immersion at the identity $1 \in G$, which follows from the fact that all vectors in the kernel exponentiate to  elements in the kernel).

Comment: But isn't it also included in the definition of a Lie subgroup $H$ of $G$ that when $m:G\times G\to G$ is the multiplication of $G$ and $i:G\to G$ is the inversion of $G$, then the restricted and corestricted maps $m|_{H\times H}^H:H\times H\to H$ and $i|_{H}^H:H\to H$ are smooth? Because if this extra condition isn't added to the definition of a Lie subgroup, how could one be sure that a Lie subgroup is actually a Lie group? And it is exactly this extra condition which I don't see is satisfied in general by $\varphi(G)$.

Comment: @RedundantAunt 1. No, those conditions are not included.

Comment: 2. A Lie subgroup is in particular a Lie group by definition.

Comment: The inversion and multiplication maps for H are smooth because H is Lie group. These are of course equal to the maps induced from G because $\phi$ is an injective  homomorphism of groups.